# Minimal downtime deployment and pipenv

Tags: python, django, pipenv

I am currently considering the switch from pip / virtualenv to [pipenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv) for my web projects (mainly Django). They use a "minimal downtime deployment" process, inspired by the one described at https://kuttler.eu/en/post/django-deployments-without-downtime/

**TL;DR**

Is there a pipenv command to create a new environment from scratch (new interpreter, no packages), then install the dependencies, then set it as the default for the current directory ?

---

Let's take a quick example. I have a project installed on my debian server, with the following structure:

```
/srv
└── project
    ├── .git/
    ├── etc/
    ├── sources/
    ├── venv_20170922/
    └── venv -> venv_20170922
```

Currently when I need to deploy it, I want to limit as most as possible the duration the website is offline. Please see this simplified views of steps I usually follow (indentation is here only to help understanding the process):

```
cd /srv/project
git pull
virtualenv -p python3 venv_20171015
source venv_20171015/bin/activate
  pip install -r sources/requirements.txt
  pushd sources
    python manage.py migrate
    python manage.py collectstatic
  popd
deactivate

supervisorctl stop myproject
# Now the website is offline
ln -f -s venv_20171015 venv
supervisorctl start myproject
# Now the website is back online
```

With this process, the website is offline only a few moment, only the time needed to stop, to update the symbolic link and to start again. Supervisor script run a gunicorn process from the environment based on "venv" path.

But how can I reproduce a similar behavior with pipenv ? As far as I know, the environment is created on the fly the first time `pipenv` command is used inside a project folder. In such case, is there some commands to fine control this behavior ?

Comment: I am confused. You say you are using a zero downtime method, when in fact you are not using one...

Comment: You are right. I actually don't use a zero DT process, but more a minimal DT process, and I pasted the wrong link. Just edited the question. The idea here is that I need to build a complete new venv from scratch each time I want to deploy, then perform a "switch venv" action at the end, so the amount of time the app is unresponding is drastically reduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using pipenv on the live server,  use it only on your development machine and create a `requirements.txt` file using the following command:

```
$ pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
```

During deployment install the packages with pip (no need to install or use pipenv at all):

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: You are right, this is more or less the solution I adopted a few months ago (this question is pretty old now ;)). But I think you gave the wrong command. It is `pipenv lock` instead of `pip` right ?